# Regex matching a string which is a semicolon-separated sequence of tokens

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to produce a Python regex string to validate the values of a column which are comma-separated sequences of unique three-letter codes from a list of three-letter (upper-cased) alphanumeric codes, e.g . the list looks something like `['XA1', 'CZZ', 'BT9', 'WFF',...]`. So valid column values could be `XA1`, `XA1;CZZ`, or `XA1;BT9;WFF;` etc. A code cannot occur in the sequence more than once.

Valid sequences must be non-empty, consist of unique codes, and may or may not terminate with a `;`, including the case where a sequence only contains one code.

If `codes` is the list of codes then the regex matching string I constructed from this is

```
match_str = '?'.join(['({};){}'.format(code, '?' if codes[-1] == code else '') for code in codes])
```

which gives me, using that example list with only four codes above

```
'(XA1;)?(CZZ;)?(BT9;)?(WFF;)?'
```

The regex match queries do produce non-null match objects for what should be valid sequences, e.g.

```
re.match(match_str, 'XA1;')
re.match(match_str, 'XA1;WFF')
re.match(match_str, 'XA1;')
```

etc.

```
In [124]: re.match(match_str, 'anystring')                                                                                        
Out[124]: <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 0), match=''>

In [125]: re.match(match_str, '')                                                                                                 
Out[125]: <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 0), match=''>

In [126]: re.match(match_str, 'XA1;something')                                                                                    
Out[126]: <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 4), match='XA1;'>
```

I want the results of all three queries above to be null, so I can use a conditional to filter out invalid values, e.g.

```
if re.match(match_str, val):
     # do something
else:
     # do something else
```

Comment: Should they come in that very order? Try `match_str = '^{}$'.format('?'.join(['({};){}'.format(code, '?' if codes[-1] == code else '') for code in codes]))`

Comment: No, the codes can also be in any order, but usually they will be a sequence of codes that respect the ordering in the list of codes. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: You are contradicting yourself, does my suggestion above work?

Comment: Not quite, but almost - so `'XA1'` fails, even though this should be valid. It seems your expression matches sequences with trailing `;` only.

Comment: If the sequence is only a single code it can be just be that value e.g. `XA1`, or `CZZ`, and this should be considered. If the sequence contains more than one code, e.g. `CZZ;WFF`, `CZZ;WFF;`, `XA1;BT9;CZZ`, then these should also be considered valid, even when there is no trailing `;`.

Comment: Is `CZZ;CZZ` valid?

Comment: No, it is not valid. Each code in the sequence should be unique.

Comment: Then forget about regex, it is too inefficient here.

Comment: Sure, there are alternatives, e.g. something like `set(s.split(';')).issubset(codes)`, with something additional to check for uniqueness. But I was just wondering if there was a regex expression for this problem.

Comment: Yes, but no one will like it and it will slow your code down up to the system freeze Use https://ideone.com/DyRrmj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions should be avoided in the situation like yours, where you want to fail strings having duplicate chunks.

Use "regular" Python:

```
codes = ['XA1', 'CZZ', 'BT9', 'WFF']
strs = ['XA1', 'XA1;CZZ', 'XA1;BT9;WFF;', 'XA1;XA1;', 'XA1;something']
for s in strs:
    chunks = s.strip(';').split(';')
    if set(chunks).issubset(codes) and len(chunks) == len(set(chunks)):
        print("{}: Valid!".format(s))
    else:
        print("{}: Invalid!".format(s))
```

See [Python demo online](https://ideone.com/DyRrmj).

**NOTES**:

- `chunks = s.strip(';').split(';')` - removes leading/trailing `;` and splits the string with `;`
- `if set(chunks).issubset(codes) and len(chunks) == len(set(chunks)):`  - checks if all the chunks we obtained are a subset of `codes` and makes sure each item inside `chunks` is unique.

Regex solution - **DON'T USE IN PRODUCTION!**

```
import re
codes = ['XA1', 'CZZ', 'BT9', 'WFF']
block = "(?:{})".format("|".join(codes))
rex =  re.compile( r"^(?!.*\b(\w+)\b.*\b\1\b){0}(?:;{0})*;?$".format(block) )
print(rex)

strs = ['XA1', 'XA1;CZZ', 'XA1;BT9;WFF;', 'XA1;XA1;', 'XA1;something']
for s in strs:
    if rex.match(s):
        print("{}: Valid!".format(s))
    else:
        print("{}: Invalid!".format(s))
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/gt39jd)

Comment: OK, thanks - this is a more straight-forward way of solving the problem, but the question was about regex.

Comment: @mrs-qv7 I can create the regex, but you must promise you won't use it. I mean it. I hate harmful solutions.

Comment: @mrs-qv7 I added a regex.

Comment: OK thanks. I am not sure I will use it, but I don't see why regex should not be used in production. Otherwise, what is the point of regex? It is actually a pattern you can describe in simple terms.

Comment: @mrs-qv7 On long non-matching strings, it will freeze the system due to excessive backtracking.

Comment: The expression is too complicated to include in production code anyway. I have posted my own solution below.

Answer (score 0):

This is a general non-regex solution to the problem of checking whether a string is a `;`-separated sequence of unique/non-repeating codes/tokens (from a fixed set of such tokens). The tokens in the string can be in any order, but only one occurrence of any token is permitted, and the string may or may not terminate with a `;`. Each token in the string must also not be surrounded by any spaces.

Example: let the set of tokens be a collection or subset of two-letter country codes such as `{'AR', 'CA', 'GB', 'HK', 'IN', 'US'}`. Then "valid" strings in the context of this problem can be those such as `AR;CA`, `HK;US;CA;GB;`, `US`, `HK;`, and invalid strings could be those such as `AR;CA`, `AR;something;HK;`, `something;AR;GB;US` etc.

```
def is_valid_token_sequence(s, tokens, sep=';'):
    s_tokens = [t for t in s.split(sep) if t]
    token_cntr = collections.Counter(s_tokens).values()
    return not (
        any(t not in tokens for t in s_tokens) or
        any(v > 1 for v in token_cntr)
    )

>>> is_valid_token_sequence('AR;CA', codes)                                                                                                                                                                                        
>>> True

>>> is_valid_token_sequence('HK;US;CA;GB;', codes)                                                                                                                                                                                 
>>> True

>>> is_valid_token_sequence('IN', codes)                                                                                                                                                                                           
>>> True

>>> is_valid_token_sequence('HK;', codes)                                                                                                                                                                                          
>>> True

>>> is_valid_token_sequence(' AR;CA', codes)                                                                                                                                                                                       
>>> False

>>> is_valid_token_sequence('1234;AR;X1;IN;CA', codes)                                                                                                                                                                              
>>> False

>>> is_valid_token_sequence('X1;AR;GB;US', codes)                                                                                                                                                                           
>>> False
```